# React y problemas en mongoose

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

estoy teniendo un problema que no alcanzo bien a comprender,
en la parte de mi backend estoy realizando una búsqueda en Mongodb, tengo dentro de la BD la colección usuario, inscripción y evento, desde el front envió una petición POST donde mando el ID del evento que he pulsado en el front, bien todo correcto, ahora creo una función donde genero un numero aleatorio, realizo sin problemas una búsqueda por el id del evento en la colección inscripción (en ella tengo _id, evento:id del evento, dorsal), los localizo, ahora quiero realizar un for para recorrer todas las inscripciones con ese evento y quiero añadirle a los dorsales el numero aleatorio.

pues no consigo esto ultimo.

```js
const AplicarDorsal = async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const eventoId = req.body.idPrueba;

    function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
      return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(0);
    }


    const evento = await Inscripcion.find({ idPrueba: eventoId });
    // console.log("Esto es el evento "+evento);
    for (let i = 0; i < evento.length; i++) {
      console.log(evento[i]);

      const dorsal = getRandomArbitrary(1, 100);

      console.log("Esto es el dorsal " + dorsal);

      const newInscripcion = {
        $push: {
          dorsal: dorsal
        }
      };
      
      const inscripcionUpdate = await Inscripcion.updateMany(evento[i]._id, newInscripcion, {
        new: true,
      });
     
      
    }


    console.log(evento);


    // for (let i = 0; i < evento.participantes.length; i++) {
    //   const dorsal = getRandomArbitrary(1, 100);

    //   const insertarDorsal = { $push: { inscrpcion: dorsal } };
    //   const eventoUpdate = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: evento.participantes[i] }, insertarDorsal, {
    //     new: true,
    //   });





    // const usuarios = await User.findOne({ email: evento.participantes[i] });

    // const insertarDorsal = { $set: { inscrpcion: [dorsal] } };

    // const eventoUpdate = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(usuarios._id, insertarDorsal);


    // console.log(eventoUpdate);
    // console.log(usuarios.inscripcion);
    // }






  } catch (err) {
    httpError(res, err);
  }
}
```

esta es la consola se queda siempre antes de entrar en la eventoUpdate y no se por que, quiero meter un dorsal y no me deja, en otro endpoint si consigo mediante findByIdUpdate agregar cosas en las otras colecciones pero aquí con el for no me deja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta seria la colección de la base de datos donde quiero introducir el dorsal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]